# Usage of 'in comparison with' when comparing features (adjectives)

Tags: grammar, word-choice, expressions

I have a problem with an expression of the form "[Adjective1] [Noun1] and [Noun2] in comparison with [Adjective2] and [Adjective3] [?]", when all adjectives are features of the given nouns and we want to compare [A1] with [A2] and [A3]. 
e.g. *Romanian literature and culture in comparison with european and global [?] |literature and culture|* 
Normally I would put in the place of [?] "ones" or maybe repeated "literature and culture" (as above), but I don't think that would be formal enough.
 Any ideas? Thanks.